# Laravel get SUM Of columns in all pages in paginator

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

i have a column in my table it name is AccountBalance
i use laravel paginator with 30 rows per page  when i use
`$paginator->sum('AccountBalance')`
it return Just sum of 30 rows in current page
i want to get sum of AccountBalance column in all pages

Comment: You cannot sum all rows if you're working with a `LengthAwarePaginator` it deliberately limits the records you have (as you've noticed). You should run a seperate query alongside the one that builds your paginator to obtain your sum, and in a perfect world you should be caching the results of both to prevent additional DB queries.

Answer (score -1):

You can do sum before, paginate.

```
$balance = AccountBalance::all();
$total = $balance->sum('total');
$paginator = $balance->paginate(100);

return view("your.view",compact('total','paginator');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).